# Can you use a maven plugin which is not in the pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm using the maven-release-plugin. It's not inside the pom.xml of the parent. I'm able to execute the command: `release:prepare` but it seems to ignore my arguments like `-Darguments='-DskipTests=true' -DskipTests=true`.

I really don't know why this is happening. could it have to do with the fact the plugin is not described in the pom?

When do you have to describe the plugin in the pom.xml?

My command looks like:

```
mvn -f "path/to/pom.xml" org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare -Darguments='-DskipTests=True' -DskipTests=true
```

The similar command works on a local project but not on some other project (not able to get it locally) which is running on jenkins. so it should be some missing configuration in my pom or project because this is working for another project

EDIT:
I've added the plugin in my pom.xml but the tests still keep running. Even with the parameter.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>${myReleaseArgs}</arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

command:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare -DdryRun -DmyReleaseArgs="-DskipTests=true"
```

Comment: Are you using command line `mvn` or - for example - Eclipse build configuration?

Comment: @pirho I've pasted my full command. I use 'mvn' as executable on the cli

Comment: So you can see tests performed & compiled when run? Have you tried to diagnose by adding property `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>` to your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I see the tests running and executed. I can not edit the pom (it's all on jenkins and a repo to which I don't have access). I give some arguments like -X and -DdryRun and they are picked up, but the argument -Darguments='-DskipTests' seems not to be picked up.

Comment: If you read the remote `pom` do you see there any stuff related to tests? I had no opportunity to test with `maven-release-plugin` but with others that i left out from `pom` (so included plugins only implicitly)  `-DskipTest=true` applied fine for goals having test phases .

Comment: In this special case yes it is...the `${argument}` can only being used if defined in a pom...

Comment: @khmarbaise how do you mean? It's not defined in the pom. It's just the plugin I want to use and skip the tests. I don't have to specifiy the plugin in my pom I think or do I? Do I have to add some special configuration to the plugin?

Comment: The `-Darguments=..` only works if you have correctly defined the plugin configuration in your pom file to use that...otherwise you can`t use `-Darguments...`...apart from that why do you need to skip the tests ?

Comment: @khmarbaise It works with the edit above! But I don't understand why it's working now (on a very basic local project I did not had to add this, and it was working too?)